# Python error - setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have been trying to run the provided code to make a color map.

The data set has `x` and `y` coordinates, and each coordinate is to have it's own color.

However, when I run the code, I get an error saying `setting an array element with a sequence`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from math import pi, sin

x, y, c = np.loadtxt('finaltheta.txt', unpack = True)

N = int(len(c)**0.5)
c = c.reshape(N,N)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(c, extent = (np.amin(x), np.amax(x), np.amin(y), np.amax(y)), cmap = cm.binary, vmin = 0.0, vmax = 1.0)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I have deduced that the error is streaming from the `np.loadtxt` line.

Comment: Sir. Could provide to us the full stacktrace?

Comment: Please, show a sample of `finaltheta.txt` so I can use for my test.

Comment: Sorry, I have been away from a computer all weekend.  It was an error in my data file that I was reading, not the code.  I thank you all for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

What is the delimiter in the file?

I can simulate this kind of load with:

```
In [223]: txt=b"1 2 3\n4 5 6".splitlines()
In [224]: a,b,c=np.loadtxt(txt,unpack=True)
In [225]: a
Out[225]: array([ 1.,  4.])
In [226]: b
Out[226]: array([ 2.,  5.])
In [227]: c
Out[227]: array([ 3.,  6.])
```

Or with a , delimited text

```
In [228]: txt=b"1,2,3\n4,5,6".splitlines()
In [229]: a,b,c=np.loadtxt(txt,unpack=True,delimiter=',')
```

How do you deduce that the error is in the loadtxt?  Normally an error gives you a stacktrace that indicates clearly where the error occurs.  It may be in `loadtxt`, but if so the trace with show that it is indeed the loadtxt call.

I can't think, off hand, of a text that would produce this error in loadtxt.  The error means that something/someone is doing something like

```
In [236]: a[0]=[1,2,3]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-236-c47480f4cd6d> in <module>()
----> 1 a[0]=[1,2,3]

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

---

There's a scattering of SO questions with `loadtxt sequence`, e.g.

[CDF Cumulative Distribution Function Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791634/cdf-cumulative-distribution-function-error)

reports the error with stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cum_graph.py", line 7, in <module>
    data = np.loadtxt('e_p_USC_30_days.txt')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 804, in loadtxt
    X = np.array(X, dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

There is also a file sample.  Unfortunately the accepted answer is just flailing around trying to suggest a cause.  I can't reproduce the error either.  That suggests that there are characters in the file that aren't reproduced in the cutnpaste and/or the user has an older numpy version and/or there's an OS issue (I'm on linux).

It would be intresting to see what the inputs to that line 804 look like, but that would require a reproducable case, and then hacking loadtxt or running it with the debugger.

I'd try `loadtxt` on a simpler, purpose built file, or try it on a portion of the problem file.  I'd also try `genfromtxt`.  In most cases it does the samething as load, but takes a sufficiently different approach that it could bypass what ever problems loadtxt has.

Comment: I deduced the error is from loadtxt by removing everything away from the code, and just having a code that reads the data file.  With that simple code, I have the same error.  If it helps, the data file is just 3 columns, and I want to read the columns into their own array.

Comment: Then there must be something unexpected in the data file.  As you see, my test cases load 3 columns into 3 variables just fine.

Comment: I've found a few old SO questions that look like yours, with more information.

Comment: I found out the error I was having.  I had an error in my data file, not the code itself.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm curious, what kind of error was it?  I'd like to reproduce it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not completely sure but sequence would refer to x, y, c. Whereas the array is the file. If you really need three variables with the file I would give them their values separately.
    
    `x = np.loadtext('finaltheta.txt')

    y = np.loadtext('finaltheta.txt')

    c = np.loadtext('finaltheta.txt')`

    
You would have to split it up in order for it to work.

Comment: Each of those calls does the same thing, read the whole file, create an array and assign it to a variable.

Comment: In his code Nathan has three variables (x, y, c) that read the file and assign it to an array, and that is what is generating the error. I merely provided and explained a solution.

Comment: 'unpack=True' splits the output into several arrays, one per column.  A mismatch between columns in the file and number of variables would produce an 'unpacking' error (same as `a,b,c=1,2,3,4` would).

Comment: According to my knowledge, the unpack=True statement assigns each column of the data file into the array.  There are 3 columns in the text file, and I want each column in its own array.